# How do I format a reference to UK legislation?

Tags: citing

I am trying to reference the Public Order Act 1986. In my reference list it should appear as:

*Public Order Act 1986*  (Accessed on 11/21/2017). url:http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/contents.

But I get:

*Public Order Act 1986* (n.d.). (Accessed on 11/21/2017). url:http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/contents.

I can move 1986 into year but then it is no longer italicized and has brackets.

Code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,firstinits,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,natbib=true, maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{refs.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\title{min}

\date{November 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\textcite{POA1986}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

% % Actually generates your bibliography.
% \bibliography{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document
}
```

bib is:

```
@ONLINE {POA1986,
title = "Public Order Act 1986",
url   = "http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/contents",
note = "[Online; accessed 27-November-2017]"
```

}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Other than the fact that you're using `biblatex` which I can guess from the `\parencite` you haven't given enough information for us to be able to answer your question. Please include a minimal complilable document that shows how you're creating your bibliography.

Comment: See the oscola package, which implements the Oxford Standard for the Citation of Legal Authorities. You would use it by replacing style=authoryear with style=oscola. You can identify a citation with @legislation which will be formatted with the appropriate oscola formatting.

Comment: @schoon -- i've changed the title so that it doesn't look like you're trying to format the actual act, only the reference.

Comment: Thanks to you all. @Ross can I do that on a per-reference basis (most of my references are Harvard)? And would it mean a separate reference list? Any example you could point me towards?